# Maven settings.xml not used

Tags: java, maven, settings, nexus

I am creating a maven module including a parent pom. This parent artifact is stored in a nexus maven repository. I added the nexus repository to my settings.xml.
Now if I am building my child module I am getting and error:
`Could not find artifact test:my.parent:pom:1.0`

It seems that the `settings.xml` is not used per default. If I add 
`<repositories><repository><id>random</id><url>http://test/repository/maven-releases/</url></repository></repositories>` to my childs pom everything works fine, the settings.xml is used and the parent artifact is found.

Am I missing anything that the settings.xml will be used per default or is this the expected behaviour?
I do not want to add this random repo tag to every of my child poms.

Parent Pom:

```
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>my.parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Modul Pom:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>my.module</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

settings.xml

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>Nexus</id>
      <url>http://mynexus:8081/repository/maven-group/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
<settings
```

Comment: Just wondering, where did you place your settings.xml? Usually it should be under `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

Comment: Yes, the `settings.xml` is placed under `${user.home}/.m2/`

Comment: Are you calling maven from command line or from IDE? IDEs often have bundled maven which has its own settings.xml file.

Comment: Tried both. IntelliJ IDEA and mvn via command line. Both not working. If I am using `mvn help:effective-settings` shows me that the correct `settings.xml` is loaded

Comment: Have you checked that the artifact can be found under the given coordinates in your repository manager ? Is the repository where it is being put within the `maven-group` ? Based on the error message `Could not find artifact test:my.parent:pom:1.0` ?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can call maven by using IDE or command line.

If you are calling from IDE, check the settings if it is mapping to your settings.xml file

If you are using command line, you can check by using `mvn --v` and it shows you where your maven home is. Then you can check your settings file under `conf/settings.xml`